# maplibregl/mapboxgl color transitions get lost after setPaintProperty

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, maplibre-gl

I want my features to smoothly transition different to colors based on its data.

For this I apply a new map.setPaintProperty but then the 'fill-color-transition' property becomes lost, forever.. Some code from a Maplibre [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/perikut/Lpgtx43v/7/)

Mapboxgl seems to have same issue [jsfiddle mapbox](https://jsfiddle.net/perikut/Lpgtx43v/11/)

layer paint property:

```
  paint: {
    'fill-color-transition': {
        duration: 3700

    },
    'fill-color': 'blue',
    'fill-opacity': .6
}

//it properly smoothly changes the colors
map.setPaintProperty('polygons-layer','fill-color','orange')

map.setPaintProperty(
    'polygons-layer',
    'fill-color',
    [
        'match',
        ['get', 'id'],
        1, 'red',
        'gray' 
    ],
    'rgba(236, 235, 235, 0.1)' // Default color for all other cases
);


setTimeout(function() {
    //transition not working anymore 
    map.setPaintProperty('polygons-layer', 'fill-color', 'orange')
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Works without problems in Mapbox GL JS, so it seems like a bug in Maplibre GL JS.

Comment: Mentioned JSFiddle is still using Maplibre.

Comment: See working JSFiddle with Mapbox GL JS: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/7e3akowc/

Comment: sorry @TomazicM i just updated the mapbox jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/perikut/Lpgtx43v/11/
  and problem persists. 
Take into account that you are not applying a new symbolization before the transition as I do below (transitions stop working then)

map.setPaintProperty(
            'polygons-layer',
            'fill-color',
            [
                'match',
                ['get', 'id'],
                1, 'red',
                'gray' 
            ],
            'rgba(236, 235, 235, 0.1)' // Default color for all other cases
        );

Comment: Yes, you are right. After filter is used in the style, transition does not work any more. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Possible workaround for this would be to create two filtered polygons layers. One would include all filtered layers that are now filtered with style filter `['get', 'id'],`, other would contain the rest. Filtering would then be done through layer `filter` option, not through style filter.